# Get values of a php in AS3

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I've managed to get a value from a sql table in my AS3 code, but I don't understand why I can't get a second value.

In my php file I've got :

```
// create SQL
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM dt_base where username = '$username'";

// execute SQL query and get result
 $sql_result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die ("Couldn't execute query.");

// get number of rows in $result.
 $num = mysql_numrows($sql_result);

$phpConfirm = "";
$phpConfirmSecond = "";
$counter = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {

 $up= $row["up"];
 $down= $row["down"];
 if ($counter == 0) {
 $phpConfirm .= $up;
 $phpConfirmSecond .= $down;

 } else {
 // Use a item limiter "|" to seperate the records
 $phpConfirm .= "|" . $up;
 $phpConfirmSecond .= "|" . $down;
 }
 $counter++;
 }
?>
```

And in my AS3 code :

```
function loadComplete(evt:Event):void {

    //Display the value with variable name "totalItem"
    total_txt.text = evt.target.data.totalItem

    //Get the value (string) with variable name "phpConfirm"
    var myResult:String = evt.target.data.phpConfirm;
    trace(evt.target.data.phpConfirm);

    var myResultSecond:String = evt.target.data.phpConfirmSecond;
    trace(evt.target.data.phpConfirmSecond);


//Split the string into an Array
    var myArray:Array = myResult.split("|");
    var myArraySecond:Array = myResultSecond.split("|");

    var finalString = "";
    var finalStringSecond = "";
    var i:int;

    for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

        finalString = finalString + myArray[i] + "<br>";
        finalStringSecond = finalStringSecond + myArraySecond[i] + "<br>";
    }

    output_txt.htmlText = finalString;
    output_txtSecond.htmlText = finalStringSecond;
}
```

`trace(evt.target.data.phpConfirm)` results with the value of "up", so it's working.
But `trace(evt.target.data.phpConfirmSecond)` results with "undefined" instead of the value of "down".

### Any idea why ?

**EDIT**

I've add that to my php file.

```
echo "phpConfirm=" . $phpConfirm . "&phpConfirmSecond=" . $phpConfirmSecond;
```

and I've change the line `$username = "John";` in order to test it in the web browser.

The result is :

phpConfirm=6h20&phpConfirmSecond=14h32

So phpConfirmSecond has a value.

But my AS3 code produce an error when I had the PhpConfirmSecond in my php file. 
Here's the error :

```
TypeError: Error #2007: Le paramètre text ne doit pas être nul.
    at flash.text::TextField/set text()
    at as3_php_mysql_01_fla::MainTimeline/loadComplete()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()
```

If I erase every trace of PhpConfirmSecond of my php file, my AS3 code works and find the value PhpConfirm.

Comment: Are you sure that your selected row(s) contain(s) a "down" value(s) ? Try to show your data before send it to flash and verify that.

Comment: Call your php file from a broswer and add the output to your question

Comment: Where in your PHP does it actually output the values?

Comment: I've edited my post with the result of the echo.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. It was the line

```
 //Display the value with variable name "totalItem"
    total_txt.text = evt.target.data.totalItem
```

that was causing all the problem...

Thank you for your help.